# WPF ListViewItem style broke the data bindings?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, gridview, listviewitem

I'm kinda new to `WPF` and I have a binding `listview` using `gridview` to display a list of objects and their properties. My entire project uses a custom style from `MaterialDesign` that gives everything a *dark-theme*.

I wanted to add `doubleclick` functionality to the items in my `listview` and I found that, I can do that by changing the style of `ListViewItem`. However that overwrote the default style from my `MaterialDesign` theme, and the items became ugly.

Then I added `BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListViewItem}}"` to restore the default style, but then the binding stopped working and it stopped displaying the properties of the objects?

Might there be a better way to add Setters to the style of an element?
And how does setting the style change anything about the data bindings?

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}"  BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListViewItem}}">
        <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="HitsoundLayer_MouseDoubleClick"/>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
<ListView.View>
    <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn Header="_Name" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
        <GridViewColumn Header="_Amount" Width="90" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Times.Count}" />
        <GridViewColumn Header="_SampleSet" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding SampleSetString}" />
        <GridViewColumn Header="_Hitsound" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding HitsoundString}" />
        <GridViewColumn Header="_Sample Path" Width="1000" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding SamplePath}" />
    </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

What I expected was a ListView that looks like as below and has working doubleclick.
[image]

But what I got was a ListView that looks like as below [image] and has working doubleclick.

This is how it looks like without `BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListViewItem}}"` [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should base your style on the [`MaterialDesignGridViewItem`](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit) resource:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignGridViewItem}">
        <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="HitsoundLayer_MouseDoubleClick"/>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a mousedoubleclick handler to the listview itself.

```
<ListView MouseDoubleClick="ListView_MouseDoubleClick"
```

And get a reference to the datacontext of the row:

```
void ListView_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var hsl = ((FrameworkElement)e.OriginalSource).DataContext as HitSoundLayer;
```

You probably have to null check hsl to avoid bad things if you double click a header or dividing line.